# Django filter objects based on property in ForeignKey set

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models that look something like this:

```py
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Instance(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I want to get a list of all `Type`s that have at least one `Instance` whose `quantity` is greater than 0. How can I express that?

In (pseudo) vanilla Python, this would be something like:

```py
[type for type in Type.objects.all()
       if type.instance_set.objects.filter(lambda instance: instance.quantity > 0)]
```

I tried

```py
available_types = Type.objects.filter(Q(instance_set__contains=Q(quantity__gt=0))
```

but this doesn't work because Django is looking for `quantity` as an attribute of `Type`, and of course doesn't find it, because it's an attribute of `Instance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter directly across a relationship:

```
Type.objects.filter(instance__quantity__gt=0)
```

Comment: Haven't tried this out yet, but `Type` doesn't have any attributes named `instance`, only `instance_set`. Further, `instance_set` doesn't directly have a `quantity` attribute; only an `Instance` would.

Comment: It doesn't matter, Django knows to follow the relationship. This will work. See the docs on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships): 'To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.'

Answer (score 2):

why not just query the Instance objects for instance.quantity > 0 and then use values_list distinct notation?

Something along the lines of:

```
types_with_quantity_gt_zero = Instance.objects.filter(quantity__gt=0).values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: `print(types_with_quantity_gt_zero, [type for type in types_with_quantity_gt_zero)` outputs `<QuerySet [2, 1]> [2, 1]`. This works if I wrap it around with `Type.objects.filter(pk__in= ...)`.